# Access object in client returned by WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service which returns a class object. How can I access these return values in my client application.

The service code:

```
public ET_ITAM_RequestDetails GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails(ET_ITAM_RequestDetails objET_ITAM_RequestDetails)
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    connect.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ET_ITAM_GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails", connect);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.AssociateID = (string)rdr[0];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.AssetID = (string)rdr[1];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.ETRequestID = (int)rdr[2];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.FreewareName = (string)rdr[3];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.InstallationCommand = (string)rdr[4];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.InstallationArguments = (string)rdr[5];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.VerificationType = (bool)rdr[6];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.VerificationPath = (string)rdr[7];
    }

    return objET_ITAM_RequestDetails;
}
```

In the client :

```
ServiceReference1.ET_ITAM_RequestDetails objItam = new 

ServiceReference1.ET_ITAM_RequestDetails();

// need to get return value.
// if i create another object it not work as expected
obj_service.GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails(objItam);
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by `ServiceReference1` it looks like you've added your WCF reference to the client solution successfully.  You are however missing the WCF client as far as I can tell.

You haven't given enough information to know what your client would be called, but your code should look something like:

```
ServiceReference1.ET_ITAM_RequestDetails objItam = new 
    ServiceReference1.ET_ITAM_RequestDetails();

// the service generation will create a WCF client for you, thought I'm not sure what your client's name would be.
objItam = obj_service.GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails(objItam);
```

---

Looking over your code again, I think I see your issue.  You did new up your wcf client, but the code for that was not provided.

```
obj_service.GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails(objItam);
```

You're simply calling the function, but not assigning its value back to your object.

```
objItam = obj_service.GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails(objItam);
```

I'm unclear on why you're newing up an empty object, passing it into your function, and returning it.  Why not just new it up and return it within the function?

```
public ET_ITAM_RequestDetails GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails()
{
    ET_ITAM_RequestDetails objET_ITAM_RequestDetails = new ET_ITAM_RequestDetails();

    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    connect.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ET_ITAM_GetAssociateFreewareRequestDetails", connect);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.AssociateID = (string)rdr[0];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.AssetID = (string)rdr[1];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.ETRequestID = (int)rdr[2];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.FreewareName = (string)rdr[3];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.InstallationCommand = (string)rdr[4];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.InstallationArguments = (string)rdr[5];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.VerificationType = (bool)rdr[6];
        objET_ITAM_RequestDetails.VerificationPath = (string)rdr[7];
    }

    return objET_ITAM_RequestDetails;
}
```

The above (and your original) will of course have (probably) unintended results if your reader has more than one row - just calling that out in case you were unaware.

Comment: **Do not use `using` with WCF clients**:  [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i have added service reference in my client successfully as follow.    ServiceReference1.ETServiceClient  obj_service = new ServiceReference1.ETServiceClient ();  I add one object of ET_ITAM_RequestDetails in client  which is return type from my service.  ServiceReference1.ET_ITAM_RequestDetails objItam = new ServiceReference1.ET_ITAM_RequestDetails();